# mainsite.urls is not a valid python path tastypie swagger

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to set up auto documentation generation using tastypie swagger, as documented [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tastypie-swagger/0.1.1). However, Django doesn't seem to be a fan of the following line in my setup:

```
TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE = 'mainsite.urls.api'
```

as evidenced by this error when I try to hit /api/doc:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/doc/
mainsite.urls is not a valid python path
```

I am working off of a Django 1.4 project I found online to introduce myself to some of the technologies. The Django structure looks like this:

```
project_directory
  src
    urls.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    etc...
    app
      models.py
      views.py
      api.py
      etc...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to cut and paste 'mainsite.urls.api'.  You're supposed to replace it with your tastypie api that you created according to the tastypie docs.

Specifically, see here:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#adding-to-the-api

If you blindly copied the tastypie setup instructions, you should have something like:

```
TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE = 'urls.v1_api'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with the current (March 2016) version of tastypie-swagger.  The setting for me that worked was this:

```
from tastypie.api import Api

v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')

v1_api.register(MyResource())

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),

    url(r'api/v1/doc/',
        include('tastypie_swagger.urls', namespace='api_tastypie_swagger'),
        kwargs={"tastypie_api_module": v1_api, "namespace": "api_tastypie_swagger"}
        ),

]
```

so tastypie_api_module is v1_api without quotes

Comment: Nothing worked. After hours of searching, this one solved it. Thanks a lot PhoebeB :-)